# Generic Property Comparison - identify property change

Tags: c#, generics, overloading, anonymous

I am mapping data between two classes where one class is a purchase order that creates or revises data in another (sales order).  I am also keeping a transaction log of what changed if the sales order value is not null.  Can you advise a way to make this generic?

```
private static DateTime CheckForChange(this DateTime currentValue, 
    DateTime newValue, string propertyName)
{
    if (currentValue == newValue) return currentValue;
    LogTransaction(propertyName);
    return newValue;
}
private static decimal CheckForChange(this decimal currentValue, 
    decimal newValue, string propertyName)
{
    if (currentValue == newValue) return currentValue;
    LogTransaction(propertyName);
    return newValue;
}
private static int CheckForChange(this int currentValue, 
    int newValue, string propertyName)
{
    if (currentValue == newValue) return currentValue;
    LogTransaction(propertyName);
    return newValue;
}
```

#### Original Proposed Code Example

```
private static T CheckForChange<T>(this T currentValue, T newValue, 
    string propertyName) where T : ???
{
    if (currentValue == newValue) return currentValue;
    LogTransaction(propertyName);
    return newValue;
}
```

#### Final revision:

```
    public static T CheckForChange<T>(this T currentValue, T newValue, 
        string propertyName, CustomerOrderLine customerOrderLine)
    {
        if (object.Equals(currentValue, newValue)) return currentValue;
        //Since I am only logging the revisions the following line excludes Inserts
        if (object.Equals(currentValue, default(T))) return newValue;
        //Record Updates in Transaction Log
        LogTransaction(customerOrderLine.CustOrderId, 
                       customerOrderLine.LineNo, 
                       propertyName, 
                       string.Format("{0} was changed to {1}",currentValue, newValue)
                       );
        return newValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are very close :) the magical solution is to use `Equals` method

```
public static T CheckForChange<T>(this T currentValue, T newValue, string propertyName)
{
    if (currentValue.Equals(newValue)) return currentValue;
    LogTransaction(propertyName);
    return newValue;
}
```

You can enhance my solution and check for nulls:

```
public static T CheckForChange<T>(this T currentValue, T newValue, string propertyName)
{
    bool changed = false;
    if (currentValue == null && newValue != null) changed = true;
    else if (currentValue != null && !currentValue.Equals(newValue)) changed = true;
    if (changed)
    {
        LogTransaction(propertyName);
    }
    return newValue;
}
```

*** EDIT ***

As in the comment, we can solve null checking problem by using `object.Equals` method:

```
public static T CheckForChange<T>(this T currentValue, T newValue, string propertyName)
{
    if (object.Equals(currentValue,newValue)) return currentValue;
    LogTransaction(propertyName);
    return newValue;
}
```

Comment: You may have to change the access specifier to something other than private as needed.

Comment: Rather than doing all of that annoying null checking yourself just use `object.Equals(a,b)` instead of `a.Equals(b)`.  The static version calls the other version after doing the appropriate null checks.

Comment: Thanks for the great answers everyone.  I will posted my final code above.